# FadeIn product card animation in jQuery doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5

I'm making product card filtering by ajax and encountered a small problem.
When a website guest goes to the page with all product cards, the cards must appear one by one with smooth animation. I made Product cards at this page with Bootstrap 5 Cards and also made ajax request to show these cards. The problem is that when a guest goes to the page with product cards, all cards are shown at the same time for 0.5 sec and then they disappear and animation with card display starts. I can't understand why this happens.

This code for cards:

```html
<div class="col">
    <div class="card border-0 bg-transparent">
        <div class="ratio" style="--bs-aspect-ratio: 62.5%;">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'full', array('class' => 'img-fluid') ); ?>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="stretched-link">
            <div class="card-img-overlay"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="card-text w-100 ps-lg-4 ps-3 fadeIn-bottom">
            <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
            <h4 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mt-lg-3 mt-1"><?php echo (get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'company_meta_key', 1 )); ?></h4>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And this my jQuery for animation:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.card').each(function(i) {
    // 'i' stands for index of each element
    $(this).hide().delay(i * 300).fadeIn(600);
  });
});


// ajax запрос
$('.cat-list_item').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.cat-list_item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {
        action: 'filter_projects',
        category: $(this).data('slug'),
      },
      success: function(res) {
        $('.post-filter').html(res);
        $('.card').each(function(i) {
          // 'i' stands for index of each element
          $(this).hide().delay(i * 300).fadeIn(600);
        });
      }
    })

  });
```

Could this animation conflict with animation when user hovers this cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging about jQuery FadeIn, I'm found solution. Need to add display:none to  with "card" class. Then all cards would be hidden while page loading. And after that FadeIn starts work correctly.